# Get content type identifier on Views

Tags: views, nodes

I am on Drupal 7 and configuring Views. I can easily add a field that displays thew node's content type. But it seems it will bring only the friendly content type name. Is there any way I can pull the content type's system name (like 'content_type_system_name')?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your field settings at the end you've a "More" section, click there and then check the "Output machine name"'s option.